# Getting reference to glsl variable during draw method?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've seen opengl examples, which use shaders, get a reference to glsl variables every frame draw like so ..

```
mColorHandle = getGL2().glGetUniformLocation(getShaderProgram(), "vColor");
gl2.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, getColorArray(), 0);
```

I don't really understand why.

Wouldn't it be better to get a reference to the glsl variable once, during initialization of custom objects. And in the objects draw only have to do this ..

```
gl2.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, getColorArray(), 0);
```

Am I missing a reason for why references to variables are constantly being updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are constantly using the same shader, you don't have to update references.

But if you use multiple shaders in your program, switching from one to another, you will have to get the reference in each of them.

Some programers don't really mind about get the reference every frame because it's not a very slow operation, so it doesn't influence a lot performances. But you are right, to keep it is better.

Comment: what do you mean by shader updates? you mean dynamically changing instructions or?

Answer (score 0):

The locations once the program is linked will never change for that program. However other programs may have other location bindings.

This means that you can in fact cache the `mColorHandle` value between draws. I recommend that you do so.